# Remove INTL extension support in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP 3.0 framework. 
Is there any way to use CakePHP framework without the intl extension support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to just install it. But in case it is absolutely impossible for you to install try this plugin:

https://github.com/hraq/cake-intl

It will fake the presence of the intl classes, but you will not be able to use any of the I18n features of CakePHP.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 3 doesn't work without, Intl extension is required
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#requirements